# How web scrape data in below URL quotes

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
 from bs4 import Beatifulsoup
 import request

 URL = ("https://parade.com/937586/parade/life-quotes/")

 web_page = requests.get(URL)

 soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page.text,"html.parser")
 quotes = []
 result = soup.find('p')

 print(result)
```

getting error.

Can anyone find locate the element? There are many quotes in the above URL. I can't find div or class for web scraping data. For one quote explain me locating element to web scrape data

Comment: What exactly do you want to scrape from that URL?

Comment: i want to scrape all quotes in  below given url for that there is no   any div or class or id to webscrape finding element .there is P tag inside they written quote  and strong tag inside author name is there . i want how to find locate element to print that quotes. if u check    first quote in url on inspect tools u will see  only p tag and strong tag , that tags how to  find elements by using webscraping that is my doubt help me

Comment: @Demon - Are you using bs4 version 4.9.3 or an older version? Otherwise using `text = str(result.next)` should work in current and older versions.

Comment: Latest version only using bs4 ,,if u don't mind can u scrape for one quote in url ,tell me finding elements ?? In this url there 150 quotes I should want to print all quotes ..for that I am not getting exact finding element location

Answer (score 1):

The quotes are formatted as JSON in a `<script>` element within the HTML and not found with `<p>` or `<div>` elements.

**Try:**

```python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
import json

r = requests.get('https://parade.com/937586/parade/life-quotes/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
result = soup.find('script', attrs={'type': "application/ld+json"})
#text = result.string # works in bs4 version 4.9.3
text = str(result.next)
# parse data as JSON
data = json.loads(text).get('articleBody')
quotes = []
for line in data.split('\n'):
    if re.match(r'\d+\.', line):
        quotes.append(line)
        #print(line)  # uncomment to print all quotes

# print first and last quotes to show all data is in the list
print("quotes=", len(quotes), sep='')
print(quotes[0])
print(quotes[-1])
```

**Output:**

```
quotes=150
1. "The purpose of our lives is to be happy." — Dalai Lama
150. “You can’t put a limit on anything. The more you dream, the farther you get.” – Michael Phelps
```

Comment: then what language did u use below code and pls can u code using beautifulsoup , i didn't find script and attribute tell me for first quote enough

Comment: showing error near line 10 object has no attribute string

Comment: @manoj - bs4 4.9.3 has string property on tag element. try `text = str(result.next)`. Does that work with you?